# How to end specifc Sub/Process in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a sub let' say Public Sub FixRows()
It takes minutes to do that process when I call that that Sub, is there anyway when the user want to cancel the process? For example he accidentally press the button and the fixrow sub runs, but he dont want to wait a minute to finish it. Because when codes run, you cannot do anything unless you wait to finish it. thanks in Advance I cant really fins an answer in google by searching

Comment: Google: `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: In a doWork event on the BackgroundWorker, Can I add my sub 'FixRows' to it? Or I just need to copy all the codes from my FixRows sub?

Comment: Just add a "Confirmation" to the button click. When user click the button - program will ask to confirm that "Are you sure you want to continue" :)